# Equation of motion for scalar field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology, symmetry, field-theory, cosmological-inflation

I am trying to derive the equation of motion for a scalar field in flat and homogenous space time where the metric is $g_{\mu \nu}=diag(-1,a^2(t),a^2(t),a^2(t))$ and the Lagrangian is given by
$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi - V(\phi)$$
The stress energy tensor is given as $$T^{\mu \nu}=\partial^\mu \phi \partial^\nu \phi -g^{\mu \nu}\mathcal{L}.$$ Since $T^{\mu \nu}=diag(\rho , p,p,p)$ so I should get $$\rho=T^{00}=\frac{1}{2}\dot \phi^2+V(\phi)$$ and $$p=T^{11}=T^{22}=T^{33}=\frac{1}{2}\dot \phi^2 -V(\phi)$$
I am not being able to get the results. There is some problem with the signs of the metric elements, and even I am getting an extra $\frac{1}{a^2(t)}$ term in $p$. Please help with the calculations.

Comment: General Relativists and Particle Physicists are in an eternal battle over the ${\it correct}$ metric sign convention. The former prefer $(+ - - \cdots )$ and use your scalar Lagrangian. The latter prefer $(- + + \cdots )$ and use the negative of your scalar Lagrangian.

Answer (score 0):

check out Rubakov Garvunov's book Introduction to the theory of the early universe in 4.8.1, "evolution of scalar field in expanding universe"

Comment: Make the variational derivative of the action equal to zero, in the context of this metric.